what is the name of event that pass only type arguments into generic function in typescript?
I am learning about typescript generics. I have created a generic function like the following:

function getRandomElement<T>(items: T[]): T {
    let ranIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
    return items[ranIndex];
}

then I intentionally called that function and passed type only (not passing argument into the function).
let result = getRandomElement<number>;

Then I expected that Ts compiler give me error message about creating result variable statement, But nothing happened. result after that became a function ((items: number[]) => number).
I want to study more about this feature of typescript. But after search a while I don't find any essential information talking about.
Could you help explain this feature or give me a keyword about it?
Thanks for considering my stupid question.

It's not really a feature of TS. In JS functions are first-class citizens - they can be assigned to variables, passed as arguments, returned from functions. The same things you can do with, say, strings or numbers. And that's what you've done - you've assigned the function getRandomElement to the variable result. It's indistinguishable (at language level) from f = () => { console.log("this is a function") } you still just assign a function to a variable. It's just through another variable: g = f

@VLAZ typescript does add tracking it's type. It differs from let result = getRandomElement; in type.

@Caleth but it's almost not related. fungtion fn<T>(x: T): T{} is TS can be called as fn<number>(42) which will first satisfy the generic parameter by passing in <number> then satisfy the regular parameter with 42. If you omit (42) from that expression, you're left with a generic function where just the generic parameter is satisfied but is not invoked. Nothing special, really - you have a two-step process but you only do the first step. Then, naturally, you're left with the second step. There is no special name for it, though. Moreover, OP expected an error with fn<number>.

getRandomElement<number> is an instantiation expression, as implemented in microsoft/TypeScript#47607 and introduced in TypeScript 4.7.
We've always been able to manually specify a generic function's type arguments when we call it, like f<X, Y>(a, b, c):
declare const f: <T, U>(x: T, y: U, z: T[]) => [T, U]
// const f: <T, U>(x: T, y: U, z: T[]) => [T, U]    

declare const a: X;
declare const b: Y;
declare const c: X[];
f<X, Y>(a, b, c); // calling a generic function

but instantiation expressions let you do that without calling it, like f<X, Y>. That is, you can now write (f<X, Y>)(a, b, c), where f<X, Y> is its own expression:
(f<X, Y>)(a, b, c); // calling an instantiation expression

The resulting function (f<X, Y>) is not generic, and can be saved to its own variable:
const g = (f<X, Y>);
// const g: (x: X, y: Y, z: X[]) => [X, Y]

This function can then be called reused with the same type arguments:
g(a, b, c);
declare const d: X;
declare const e: Y;
g(d, e, [a, d]); 

Playground link to code

I have another question related to this discussion "Why does typescript not allow to partially specify type arguments in order to create a new generic function from another generic function that have more generic param"
type A = { a: string }; function mergeFunc<T_1, T_2>(a: T_1, b: T_2) { return { ...a, ...b }; } let newGenMerge = mergeFunc<A, Tp>; 
In that, A is type argument used to make generic function more specified, Tp is a generic type parameter (type placeholder). So newGenMerge is still generic function with one generic type param. However TS not allow that,

Play ground link of code example above

type signature of mergeFunc is: mergeFunc<T_1, T_2>(a: T_1, b: T_2): T_1 & T_2. Both T_1 and T_2 are type parameters. I want to create a new generic function from mergeFunc using instantiation expression. The new one is more specified than mergeFunc But it's not completely normal function ( function that don't have any type parameter), It's still generic function. I did that by passing actual type A to the first type parameter and keeping the second type param by type param (Tp) which is used as type parameter in the new created generic function (newGenMerge ).

When I run the code above, I expect that: newGenMerge is a generic function and its signature will become: newGenMerge<Tp>(a: A, b: Tp): A & Tp. In that, A is the actual type while Tp is a type parameter ( type placeholder). However, Typescript compiler does not permit me to do that. Could you give the reason?

This really isn't the proper place to have such a discussion; if you have a followup question you should probably make a new post for it.

Ironically, what you just did with the line below is quite normal in many programming languages:
let result = getRandomElement<number>;

You merely assigned a function to variable and this is completely valid in JavaScript/Typescript. That is why TypeScript won't complain - you haven't done nothing wrong - not just yet ;-)
Notice that you are not calling the function... only merely assigning it to another variable. This also means that you can simply call the assigned function directly, if you wish, as in:
const dummyItems = ["one", "two", "three"];
const assignedFunction = getRandomElement<string>;
const resultOfRunningAssignedFunction = assignedFunction(dummyItems);

That line of code ( function invocation ) is necessary if your intent would be to see something happen. In other words, you may need to call a function to see any reasonable output/result.
